# Normals looking bad when tapering

Tags: modeling, edges, normals

[image]

This is my problem. The normals look too sharpwhere the carrot gets thinner and it just destroys any maps i put on it. If I add a lot more geometry the problem smoothes itself out. But I can't afford that much geometry as this is meant for a mobile game. Does anyone know of another way to deal with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15283508/1679849)

Answer (score 1):

You could try some Smooth Vertex to a couple of the edge loops.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to help a lot but it doesn't quite fix the problem.